# Switching whole master layout in asp.net mvc

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am doing an ASP.NET MVC 5 website with AngularJS.

I want to have a web site (SEO) and a web application site (AngularJS).

I want to switch to the SPA via "Go to SPA" link.
I want to switch back to the website via click on the home/house icon on the SPA.

When I do this switching I want to exchange the whole layout.

How would I do this with asp.net mvc?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write your website as you would a standard MVC app. Then write an MVC controller that returns the .cshtml file of your angular app and set `Layout = null;` at the top. With this approach you can access everything through the .NET MVC routing and controllers and your angular app doesn't have any of your MVC layout in it.

Comment: Hm... one side effect. I get an exception when I put the Renderbody inside that .cshtml file but I would need that. Because I want to partly use mvc in the SPA too. Any tip?

Comment: Detail of the exception is always helpful. I think the only way to achieve that would be to define as secondary layout with nothing in it and reference that on your Spa page.

Answer (score 0):

Just create two main .cshtml files. One cshtml for the regular app, and the second for the angular app with ng-view.

 Now about swithcing from one file to another use window.location.href = 'your-cshtml-file'.

Comment: Of course I should create two .cshtml files I implicitly wrote that in my own words... Switching via windows.location.href is not needed using asp.net mc.